# FutureBuilder always refresh

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a function for asking that u have token apikey or not. but when im trying to get some textfield there, i cant texting in it(always refresh causing that futurebuilder i think).
below is the function.

```
Future<String> getApiKey() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.getString("apikey");
}
FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: getApiKey(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return Center(
            child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
          );
        default:
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print("has error");
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          } else if (snapshot.data == null) {
            print("not login");
            // return Container();
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.asset("assets/image/images/nodata.svg",
                      height: 150),
                  SizedBox(height: 15),
                  Text(
                    "no data",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: baseColor,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        fontFamily: "Sofia"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return FutureBuilder<List<LineUpListModel>>(
              future: prov.setLineUpList(prov),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return Center(
                      child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
                    );
                  default:
                    if (snapshot.hasError)
                      return Center(
                          child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                    else if (snapshot.data == null)
                      // return Container();
                      return Center(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            SvgPicture.asset(
                                "assets/image/images/nodata.svg",
                                height: 150),
                            SizedBox(height: 15),
                            Text(
                              "no data",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: baseColor,
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  fontFamily: "Sofia"),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    else {
                      print(prov.getMyProfileModel.apiKey.toString());
                      return TextField();
                    }
                }
              },
            );
          }
      }
    },
  ),
```

How can I type in the TextField without any refreshing interruptions from the Futurebuilder?  what should I fix?

Answer (score 0):

You can take this approach for all of your future builder.

```
Future _future;

@override
@initState() {
   _future = getApiKey();
}
```

Now in your FutureBuilder use this _future variable.

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: _future,
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might come from your `future: getApiKey()` because you are not saving an instance of your future value so it will be reloaded each time the `build()` method is called (which will happen a lot). A solution might be to keep your future instance inside a variable and initializing it only one time (you will need a `StatefulWidget`):

```dart
Future<String> _futureString;

@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   _futureString = getApiKey();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: _futureString,
   );
}
```

By doing so the `_futureString` variable will keep the value of your asynchronous operation and won't reload every time.